How to call Dynamics 365 and impersonate the calling user?
I have a custom ASP.NET Core 8.0 web application from where I want to call Dynamics 365 and impersonate the currently logged in Windows user.
This code works when calling an on-premise installation of Dynamics v9.1, but when using the same code to call Dynamics365 in the cloud, I get "unauthorized". I'm guessing something does not work the same with the cloud-version of Dynamics but I can't figure out how to fix that so I'm hoping for some suggestions from you guys.
I'm running the code locally now for development so I'm impersonating myself and I am system administrator both on-premise and in cloud.
The code (where the method Get() is the starting point and is called earlier in my application):
protected virtual async Task<string> Get()
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true };

    // The guid is a system administrator
    return await WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(_user.AccessToken, () => 
       GetAsync("https://myorganizationname.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/", 
                "systemusers(E8F2BDBD-540C-EF11-9F89-000D3A4C32E3)", handler)); 
}

private async Task<string> GetAsync(string baseUrl, string url, H (ttpClientHandler handler)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);        
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

        try
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                if (response.GetType() == typeof(HttpResponseMessage))
                {
                    throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase); // I always get "Unauthorized" as ReasonPhrase...
                }

                throw new Exception(json);
            }

            return json;
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
        {
            // Just some error handling...
        }
    }
}

As mentioned, this code works fine when calling an on-premise instance of Dynamics...
What can I do to make it successfully call a cloud instance?

Your code attempts to use Windows impersonation to access the cloud-based Dynamics 365, which is totally different from on-premises Dynamics. Cloud-based Dynamics 365 does not support Windows Authentication or Windows Identity-based impersonation for authentication. Instead, it relies on OAuth 2.0 for authentication, which requires an Azure Active Directory (AAD) registered application, so you have to use one of the authentication mechanism mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/authenticate-oauth as follows:
 using (HttpClient httpClient2 = new HttpClient())
        {
            var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", Resource),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", ClientId),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", ClientSecret),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials")
            });
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient2.PostAsync(Authority, formContent);
            return !response.IsSuccessStatusCode ? null : response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }

To impersonate a specific user in Dynamics 365 Online from a web application, you need to authenticate using Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) and set the MSCRMCallerID header in your HTTP requests. The MSCRMCallerID header allows you to perform operations on behalf of another user by specifying their user ID (GUID).
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        
        // Set the MSCRMCallerID header for impersonation
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("MSCRMCallerID", userId);

        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Error: {response.StatusCode}, {response.ReasonPhrase}");
        }

        return content;
    }

Please mark this answer as verified if you are ok with answer and let me know if you have any other questions. thanks

Thank you for the reply! I think I understand this concept since I have been working with integrations to Dynamics365 Online where I've used a "client/secret" approach. But how would I figure out the "userId" from the current user if I have to call Dynamics365 as the "application user"? As far as I understand I have to f.e figure out the current user based on the email address that I can read from the impersonation/windows  identity and then fetch that user from D365 Online... Or pass the userId from Online from a form script or similar...

If I got what you mean correctly, you will get the current logged in user id by retrieving from CRM the related record using the email address, isn’t? Then after you return the related user you can do the needed action by passing the user ID to the action. If this is not what you mean just please tell me what you’re trying to achieve with this functionality exactly

I think you understood me correctly, and I think that's what I need to do to be able to "impersonate" the user. It's a bit tedious but it is doable. Thank You for the pedagogical explanation!

A small followup question: setting MSCRMCallerID when doing a "WhoAmI"-call seems to have no effect, do you know if that is "normal"? Also, instead setting header "CallerObjectId" as per the recommendations from Microsoft resulted in a "Forbidden" response. I guess that "systemuserid" is not the same as "entra id" and I cannot figure out how to resolve this "entra id" instead... But we'll see what happens..

could you please show me your code?

I had time yesterday to do some further testing. For what I can conclude, setting the "CallerId" when performing a WhoAmI will still return the identity of the appuser. But performing any CRUD action will result in the action being performed as the "CallerId" (which is good). These are my observations after creating a CrmServiceClient in C#. I still have to test if setting the "MSCRMCallerID" when creating an HttpClient has the same effect but hopefully, and likely, it does. Thanks!
